# iOS builds (ipa file) generated by Expo is too large

Tags: ios, react-native, ipa, expo

I'm using Expo for a react native project. I used to get apk and ipa files close to 30 MB when I use `exp build:android` and `exp build:ios`. Recently I updated `exp` version to `53.0.0` and added an iPhone X to my Apple developer account. Since then I'm getting ipa file size above 170MB. I have not made any changes to my code or `app.json`. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

I know this doesn't matter when I upload to App Store or Test Flight, but this is not an option for my project since we are using enterprise distribution and Diawi for testing purposes.

Comment: This is probably because expo is building all of the natives plugins in your app. No matter if you use them or not.

Comment: Expo is including bitcode, that's why the size is large (I think). Is this because I added iPhone X? Is there any way I can exclude bitcode in expo builds?

Answer (score 0):

if you are building the app by using Expo. you should read [this link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v26.0.0/introduction/why-not-expo) carefully. It will explain to you why the size of IPA is too large.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had gone through that page before. I've also gone through expo forums. They said we can expect large apk/ipa sizes, but that too in range of 30 MB. My builds are larger than 170 MB.

Comment: This size is probably due mostly to app thinning and bitcode, and final download size should be much smaller.

Comment: @dikaiosune Yes, this size is not a problem when we upload to app store. But in my case, we're distributing through Diawi. The installed app  size is above 330 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason and solution for this issue.

Reason: This only happens when I let expo handle the build process and certificate management automatically.

Solution: Generate and provide the provision certificates and other certificates manually. Do not let Expo handle everything.